# Count elements based on 2 columns in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I have an array being created (and working) where I have multiple rows, with 4 columns.

An example of the output:

```
Array (
modid => XYZ
year => 2017
name => Civic 2DR Auto
color => Blue
)
```

Now, I have several results... what I want to do is output a summary.

IE

```
XYZ 2017 Civic 2DR Auto Blue: 2
XYZ 2017 Accord 4DR Auto: Red 1
XYZ 2017 Accord 4DR Auto: Green 4
```

How can I loop through the array and count when 2 cols match, IE 'name' and 'color'?

Comment: How about year?

Comment: Create nested associative arrays whose keys are the columns that you want to match. Loop through your array, and increment the counter in `$counter_array[$el['name']]][$el['color']]`

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: is the field _modid_ supposed to be a unique identifier?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have unique array keys to count over them.

For example;

```
$inputarr = array(); // multidimensional array you provided

$col1 = "name";
$col2 = "color";

$countarr = array();
foreach($inputarr as $arr) {
    $key = str_replace(".","",$arr[$col1])."-".str_replace(".","",$arr[$col2]);
    if(!isset($countarr[$key])) { $countarr[$key]=0; }
    $countarr[$key]++;
}

print_r($countarr);
```

You can later explode $countarr keys with dot and dash to build your table.

This might not look very nice, but should solve the problem.

Good luck